# Complexity of an NFA

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, nfa

I have seen in several sources (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32308217), [2](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/lectures/01/Slides01.pdf) - page 160), that the complexity of running through an NFA is O(m²n). However I haven't understood why it is so.

My intuition is that the complexity should be O(m^n) (where m is the length of the string, and n is the number of states), because for each letter in the input string, there are n possible states that the NFA can move to them.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to follow all possible paths to get final a state read [Ambiguity in transition: How to process string in NFA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617429/ambiguity-in-transition-how-to-process-string-in-nfa/15661281#15661281)

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan Thank you for the comment, but I still don't get why it has to be O(m²n)...
I'll edit my main question with more explanation about what's my intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think about how we'd do one step of simulating the NFA. We begin in some set of active states Q<sub>init</sub>. For each state we're in, we look at all the outgoing transitions labeled with the current symbol, then gather them into a set Q<sub>mid</sub>. Next, we follow all possible ε-transitions from those states and keep repeating this process until there are no more ε-transitions to follow (that is, we find the ε-closure), giving us our new set of state Q<sub>next</sub>. We then repeat this process once per character in the input.

So how much time does this take? Well, there are m characters in the input string, so the runtime is m times whatever work we do on one individual character. Each state can have at most n transitions leaving it on each character, so the time to iterate over all the characters in Q<sub>init</sub> to find the set Q<sub>mid</sub> is O(n<sup>2</sup>): there are O(n) states in Q<sub>init</sub> and we only need to scan O(n) transitions per state. From there, we have to keep following ε-transitions until we run out of transitions to follow. We can do that by doing a BFS or DFS starting simultaneously from each state in Q<sub>min</sub> and only following ε-transitions. The NFA can have at most O(n<sup>2</sup>) ε-transitions total (one between each pair of states), so the BFS or DFS will run in time O(n<sup>2</sup>). Overall we're doing O(n<sup>2</sup>) work per character, so the total work done is O(mn<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: You mention that the time to iterate over all characters is O(n^2) and that the NFA can have at most O(n^2) epsilon transitions total. Does that mean you reduced O(m(n^2 + n^2)) to O(mn^2)?